Is DynamoDB a good choice for a multi-tenant file management service?
I am planning to build a file management microservice for a multi-tenant SaaS platform that uses Amazon S3 as the file storage backend. I intend to use DynamoDB as the database because it is fast and scalable. The platform may host many tenants, with each tenant having many users, and each user having many files in their storage space.
I need to keep a record of each file's metadata and the user directory structure (hierarchy) in the database. However, I'm uncertain if DynamoDB is the best choice. A user might want to list all their directories and files, search by name, or sort them alphabetically or by creation date. This could lead to the "hot partition" problem (at least for Global Secondary Indexes). The situation could become even more challenging when tracking all the files uploaded by all users within a tenant.
Therefore, I am considering a hybrid approach: using PostgreSQL for relational data and DynamoDB for storing file information and directory hierarchies.
What are your thoughts on this idea? Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.


I intend to use DynamoDB as the database because it is fast and scalable.

Not any more so than any other mainstream database system, such as SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc, to name a few.

I need to keep a record of each file's metadata and the user directory structure (hierarchy) in the database. However, I'm uncertain if DynamoDB is the best choice.

Probably not. DynamoDB is a NoSQL key-value store database used for looking up specific pieces of data by a key....

A user might want to list all their directories and files, search by name, or sort them alphabetically or by creation date.

...And these are mostly relational sounding use cases and data objects.

Therefore, I am considering a hybrid approach: using PostgreSQL for relational data and DynamoDB for storing file information and directory hierarchies.
What are your thoughts on this idea? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

There's no point in trying to maintain two database systems here. Just store all the data in a single RDBMS like PostgreSQL and call it a day. It'll perform just as a well there when architected correctly, being relational data. Especially since hierarchical data is tree-like in nature which is naturally modeled by the type of indexes that RDBMS use.
I speak with experience working with "big data" in multi-tenant database servers of the RDBMS kind, on modest hardware (actually that were hosted on AWS), whose queries usually ran in under a second.

Thank you for your response. Can I ask how much data you managed to handle on modest hardware (could you give the specs too)? You know DynamoDB is distributed and cost-effective, anyway what AWS service do you suggest for this scenario?

@Majid Np! Some rough metrics: We had tables with 10s of billions of rows and terabytes of data big (in single tables), growing around 1 billion rows a year, supporting about 1,000 tenant databases, and essentially a 24/7 uptime. This was all managed in SQL Server in an AWS VM provisioned 8 CPU cores and 16 GB of Memory. "You know DynamoDB is distributed" - Distributed systems are overrated, even the devs of MongoDB (another NoSQL system thought of for its Sharding capabilities) agree: Myth 5

Thank you, @J.D., for the valuable metrics and insightful details.

@Majid Sure thing, best of luck!
